# Amazon Redshift: Check column names during COPY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

Can I check columns names during copy from S3 to Redshift?

For example, I have "good" CSV:

```
name ,sur_name
BOB , FISCHER
```

And I have "wrong" CSV:

```
sur_name,name
FISCHER , BOB
```

Can I check names of columns during copy command?

I don't want to use AWS Glue or AWS Lambda for checks because I don't want to open/load/save the same file many times.

(The same problem for other files with columns names.)

This is very simple check so Redshift should allowed that but I can't find any information about that.

Or if this is not possible? Can you give me some idea how do it without reading all files?

(For example, a Lambda function that reads only headers without getting all file.)

Answer (score 0):

From [Column mapping options - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-column-mapping.html):

> You can specify a comma-separated list of column names to load source data fields into specific target columns. The columns can be in any order in the COPY statement, but when loading from flat files, such as in an Amazon S3 bucket, **their order must match the order of the source data**.

Therefore, the only way to read such files would be to specify the column names in their correct order. This requires you to look inside the file to determine the order of the columns.

When reading an object from Amazon S3, it is possible to specify the **range** of bytes to be read. So, instead of reading the entire file, it could read just the first 200 bytes (or whatever size would be sufficient to include the header row). An AWS Lambda function could read these bytes, extract the column names, then generate a COPY command that would import the columns in the correct order (without having to read the *entire* file first).